# How to split a string by 2 strings in Java

Tags: java, string, text, split, cpu-word

How do I split this string by two words?

```
<input type="hidden" name="SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN" value="2f56248e-e54d-48ef-8c8c-6028d6f3d63f" id="SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN" />
```

String 1:      `value="`

String 2:     `" id="SYNC`

After every split the string need to look like: `2f56248e-e54d-48ef-8c8c-6028d6f3d63f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a regex to extract the value of interest. This way your code does not make any assumptions and will not break if there is something completely different after `value=...`

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SplitString {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN\" value=\"2f56248e-e54d-48ef-8c8c-6028d6f3d63f\" id=\"SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN\" />\n";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("value=\"[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()){
            String keyValue = matcher.group(0);
            String key = keyValue.split("=")[0];
            String value = keyValue.split("=")[1];
            System.out.println("KeyValue: " + keyValue);
            System.out.println("Key: " + key);
            System.out.println("Value: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this

```
KeyValue: value="2f56248e-e54d-48ef-8c8c-6028d6f3d63f"
Key: value
Value: "2f56248e-e54d-48ef-8c8c-6028d6f3d63f"
```